# UIAutomation - command line issue

Tags: ios, command-line, xcode6, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I would like to access the SETTINGS and turn on/off WiFi.
Therefore I am running the following command:

```
instruments -v -w [my_phpne_ID] -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/Applications/Preferences.app -e UIASCRIPT /Users/test/Documents/xCode/Shell-Script/mytest.js -e UIARESULTSPATH /Users/test/Documents/xCode/Shell-Script
```

The following issue pops up:

```
Instruments : Instrument 'Automation - Preferences' rejected command 'Instrument Command (purpose:Trace;
```

Do I need to initialize the phone and Xcode somehow?

It usually works after I run a dummy App from Xcode on the phone.
But I would like to avoid it and run this command directly without any dummy App.